# How to edit configuration in MoveIt?

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

With the MoveIt Setup Assistant I managed to generate a configuration as described in one of the MoveIt tutorials.
Now I want to edit that particular configuration by pressing the 'Edit Existing MoveIt Configuration Package'  button. I would expect that you can browse to the folder where the configuration is stored and open it. In my case '*home/catkin_ws/src/test_moveit_config*'.  But all the files in that and the underlaying folders are greyed out.
Has this something to do with the fact that the right file is not present in those folders? Or does it might have something to do with access rights from Ubuntu?
Online I am unable to find anything that points me in the right direction as in every tutorial new configurations are made instead of editing existing ones.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Solution:
Open the folder that contains the package.xml in you saved configuration. No need to open a particular file as the configuration is stored as a package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348630/how-to-edit-configuration-in-moveit?/) by [BrandDebiel](https://answers.ros.org/users/53294/branddebiel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2020-04-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I would expect that you can browse to the folder where the configuration is stored and open it. In my case '*home/catkin_ws/src/test_moveit_config*'.  But all the files in that and the underlaying folders are greyed out.
> Has this something to do with the fact that the right file is not present in those folders? Or does it might have something to do with access rights from Ubuntu?

Loading *an existing configuration* means loading a *package*. A package is a set of files in a directory with a manifest (ie: a `package.xml`).

So in order to open an existing configuration, you do typically browse to the folder and then click load.

If that is not possible for you then please add a screenshot to your question text, preferably with some highlights indicating where you believe you should be able to click and what isn't working for you.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BrandDebiel](https://answers.ros.org/users/53294/branddebiel/) on 2020-04-07**:
Got, it! Works like charm. I already figured it couldn't be that difficult.
Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [MucahitErbay](https://answers.ros.org/users/148268/mucahiterbay/) on 2023-05-09**:
Hi, I have a same problem. I want to edit that particular configuration by pressing the 'Edit Existing MoveIt Configuration Package' button. Then I choose the relevant folder. But I get an error. The error is: The choosen package location exists but was not created using moveit setup assistant. If this is a mistake, provide the missing file: /home/merbay/moveit_ws/src/robot_arm_urdf/urdf/.setup_assistant
Thank you for any helping.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-05-10**:
I would suggest to post a new question.

Visibility of comments under questions with accepted answers from 3 years ago is going to be *very* low.